# Generic WPF multithread access to Controls

Tags: c#, wpf, thread-safety

I have this extension method I use in WinForms but would like to know how I can implement the same concept with WPF.

```
public static void SafeThreadAction<T>(this T control, Action<T> call)
    where T : System.Windows.Forms.Control
{
  if(control.InvokeRequired)
    control.Invoke(call, control);
  else
    call(control);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think WPF's version would look like this:

```
public static void SafeThreadAction<T>(this T control, Action<T> call)
    where T : System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherObject
{
  if (!control.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
    control.Dispatcher.Invoke(call, control);
  else
    call(control);
}
```

Comment: Gabe, I don't think you need the second argument in the call to Invoke(), since you are already calling the control's dispatcher. Adding the call priority argument might also be worth considering.

Comment: @Alan: The second argument is required because `call` is an `Action<T>` and not just an `Action`.